# Multiple db appender in log4j?

Tags: java, database, logging, cassandra, log4j

How to create log tables date wise?
**Example :**
for 26-08-2015 log table name should be '**logTable_26_08_2015**',
     for 27-08-2015 new log table should be created with name '**logTable_27_08_2015**'(similar to  log4j.RollingFileAppender).
Currently i'm using Cassandra db.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml configuration file, you have to set a layout to your appender :

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="logTable_%d{dd_MM_yyyy} *%-5p* %c{1}: %m (%F, line %L)%n"/>
     </layout>
</appender>
```

This layout should work.
More information [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).